# I created a splashscreen its working but it didnt solve what i needed i had how can i load the constructor while the splahshscreen is loading?

Tags: c#, winforms

In the top of form1 i did:

```
InitializeComponent();

            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SplashScreen));
            t.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            textBox3_text_valid = 0;
            label8.Visible = false;
            label8.Visible = false;
            Logger.exist();
            dt1 = DateTime.Now;
            label1.Text = dt1.ToLongTimeString();
            temperature_label = new Label();
            textMode_label = new Label();
            this.Controls.Add(textMode_label);
            this.Controls.Add(temperature_label);

            temperature_label.Location = new Point(260, 200);
            temperature_label.Height = 250;
            temperature_label.Width = 500;
            temperature_label.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            temperature_label.Font = new Font("Arial", 35, FontStyle.Bold);

            textMode_label.Location = new Point(350, 200);
            textMode_label.Height = 250;
            textMode_label.Width = 500;
            textMode_label.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            textMode_label.Font = new Font("Arial", 35, FontStyle.Bold);
            textMode_label.Text = " - הטמפרטורה כעת";

            path_log = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath) + @"\log";
            fullPath = path_log + log_file_name;

            timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer.Interval = 100;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            timer.Start();
            textBox3.Text = Options_DB.Get_textBox3_time();
            computer = new Computer();
            computer.Open();
            computer.GPUEnabled = true;

            t.Abort();
```

The problem i have is with the line:

```
computer.Open();
```

Its taking like 3-5 seconds untill its doing this line.
So i added a splahscreen code in the constructor i did:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SplashScreen));
t.Start();
Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

And then:

```
t.Abort();
```

Then:

```
public void SplashScreen()
        {
            Application.Run(new SplashScreen());
        }
```

In the SplashScreen form i did:

```
public partial class SplashScreen : Form
    {
        public SplashScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SplashScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Increment(1);
            if (progressBar1.Value == 100) timer1.Stop(); 
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when the SplashScreen is over to load the progressBar is at 100% finished to move to the right the program is waiting for the computer.Open(); line to be finished.

I wanted that while the progressBar in the splashscreen is working it will do all the stuff in the constructor including the computer.Open();

So when the splashscreen is finished it will display my program ato nce without waiting.

How can i do it ?

EDIT**

This is what i did now in the top of form1:

```
Computer computer = new Computer();
SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen();
```

Then the constructor:

```
InitializeComponent();

            Task.Run(() => computer.Open())
    .ContinueWith(t => { }
        , new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Token)
    .ContinueWith(t => splash.Close());
            textBox3_text_valid = 0;
            label8.Visible = false;
            label8.Visible = false;
            Logger.exist();
            dt1 = DateTime.Now;
            label1.Text = dt1.ToLongTimeString();
            temperature_label = new Label();
            textMode_label = new Label();
            this.Controls.Add(textMode_label);
            this.Controls.Add(temperature_label);

            temperature_label.Location = new Point(260, 200);
            temperature_label.Height = 250;
            temperature_label.Width = 500;
            temperature_label.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            temperature_label.Font = new Font("Arial", 35, FontStyle.Bold);

            textMode_label.Location = new Point(350, 200);
            textMode_label.Height = 250;
            textMode_label.Width = 500;
            textMode_label.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            textMode_label.Font = new Font("Arial", 35, FontStyle.Bold);
            textMode_label.Text = " - הטמפרטורה כעת";

            path_log = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath) + @"\log";
            fullPath = path_log + log_file_name;

            timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer.Interval = 100;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            timer.Start();
            textBox3.Text = Options_DB.Get_textBox3_time();
            computer = new Computer();
            computer.Open();
            computer.GPUEnabled = true;

            Application.Run(splash);
            Application.Run(new Form1() { Computer = computer });
```

Im getting 3 errors:

1. Error    1   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for 'Run'   D:\C-Sharp\NvidiaTemp\NvidiaTemp\NvidiaTemp\Form1.cs
2. Error    2   'System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments
3. Error    3   'NvidiaTemp.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'Computer'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a new thread to handle the UI of your splash screen so that your first UI thread can continue on to do some other non-UI based processing.

Don't do that.

Multiple UI threads are a **really** bad idea.  They're very hard to work with, result in buggy code, don't play well with framework code, etc.  Just don't do it unless you *really* know what you're doing, and even then, avoid it at all costs.

Instead, do the non-UI work in a non-UI thread, and do all of your UI work, for the entire application, in a single UI thread.

The other issue is that we'll want are splash screen to be shown before our main form is shown, so to handle that we'll move to the program.cs file to alter how the entire application is started.

First we'll create the splash screen and the object to handle the long running work, then start that long running work in another thread, and instruct it to close the splash screen when it's done.  (Note that we're closing the form nicely here, rather than using `Abort`.  `Abort` is something else to avoid at all possible costs.)

Then we just show the splash screen in the main thread, and when it has been closed, we show the main form.  We also pass in the results of the long running process to the main form, so you'll need to create a property for it to be able to have those results passed into.  We'll also be able to leverage the cancellation capabilities of the Task Parallel Library to ensure that the splash screen is closed after 5 seconds, even if the task isn't completed at that point:

```
SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen();
Computer computer = new Computer();
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAny(new[]{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => computer.Open()),
    Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
},
t => splash.Close());

Application.Run(splash);
Application.Run(new MainForm() { Computer = computer });
```

And here's a `Delay` implementation, since you're using 4.0 and don't have access to the one added in 4.5:

```
public static Task Delay(TimeSpan timeout)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    new System.Threading.Timer(_ => tcs.TrySetResult(true),
        null, (long)timeout.TotalMilliseconds, Timeout.Infinite);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Servy tried your code but im getting errors. Updated my question now.

Comment: @user3117033 It's because you're using .NET 4.0, several of those features were added in 4.5.  See edits.  As for your third point, I already mentioned that in my answer; you need to add a new property so that it can be passed in.