# Splash Screen Not Closing Based Off Progress Bar

Tags: c#, multithreading, splash-screen

Form1.cs

```
public Form1()
    {
        Thread SplashThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SplashScreen));
        SplashThread.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        SplashThread.Abort();

        InitializeComponent();

        this.BringToFront();

        PlayerOne[1] = new BladeWarrior();
        PlayerOne[2] = new FistWarrior();
        PlayerOne[3] = new Archer();
        PlayerOne[4] = new RedMage();
        PlayerOne[5] = new BlueMage();

    }
    public void SplashScreen()
    {
        Application.Run(new SplashScreen());
    }
```

SplashScreen.cs

```
public SplashScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            LoadGearFiles LoadGear = new LoadGearFiles();

            LoadGear.StartPatching(this);

        }
        Timer t = new Timer();


        void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (LoadingBar.Value == 100) t.Stop();

        }
```

LoadGearFiles.cs

```
public void StartPatching(SplashScreen Splash)
        {
            Splash.PatchingLabel.Text = "Patching in progress! This may take a moment or two!";
            Thread.Sleep(SleepTime);
            Splash.LoadingBar.Value += 25;

            LoadWeapons(Splash);
            Splash.LoadingBar.Value += 25;
            LoadArmor(Splash);
            Splash.LoadingBar.Value += 25;
            LoadRings(Splash);
            Splash.LoadingBar.Value += 25;
            Splash.PatchingLabel.Text = "Patch Complete!";
        }
```

My problem is that my Splash Screen shows but closes based of the Thread.Sleep(5000) and not the progress bar value being equal to its maximum. If I comment out Thread.Sleep(5000) the splash screen closes almost instantly. In the LoadGearFiles class, there's nothing special, its just stream readers/writers reading and writing to notepad files,loading the information into arrays. They read/write/populate successfully. Also, in the load gear files class, I increase the value of the progress bar after certain files are read from or written to. What seems to be my problem here. What sort of logical/syntactical approach should I take?

Comment: What happens if you remove your `SplashThread.Abort();` call? Or more directly, why do you have that `Abort()` call in there?

Comment: And what version of C# are you using? 4.0+ has easier ways of handling threading situations like this.

Comment: If I comment out SplashThread.Abort(); the splash screen wont close at all. The other form will pop up and the splash screen will stay up in the background. 

@ledbutter How can I check which version I am using?

Comment: Right-click on your project, select "Properties" and on the Application tab there is a "Target framework" combo box, the value displayed there is the version of C# you are using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I created a splashscreen its working but it didnt solve what i needed i had how can i load the constructor while the splahshscreen is loading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861988/i-created-a-splashscreen-its-working-but-it-didnt-solve-what-i-needed-i-had-how)

Comment: I'm using framework 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using WinForms from your code. It looks like you want to show the splash screen for a minimum duration, or until all files are loaded successfully -- whichever comes **last**.

Assuming you have access to the C# 4.0's `Task` and the `async/await` keywords of C# 5.0, I'd highly recommend staying away from `Thread.Sleep`. It's a fairly old construct that is not very efficient for modern multithreading programs. Even if you don't have the latter, using `Task` is preferred and you will see why the more you use them.

Let's break down your logic into tasks:

1. Show the Splash Screen.
2. Load in a data file asynchronously.
3. Update progress on the UI thread.
4. Repeat steps 2-3 for each additional data file.
5. Ensure the Splash Screen has been displayed for at least *n* seconds.
6. Close the splash screen.

Let's look at it in a form of C# code (which I'm writing largely off the top of my head, not in an IDE):

```
public async void ShowSplashScreen(TimeSpan minimumDuration)
{
    // Show the splash screen to the user.
    var splashScreen = new SplashScreen();
    splashScreen.Show();
    splashScreen.UpdateProgress(0);  // reset progress bar

    // Record when we started to load data for calculating the elapsed time later on.
    var startTime = DateTime.Now;

    // Load all of our data types asynchronously from file.
    var warrior = await LoadDataFileAsync("warrior.dat");
    splashScreen.UpdateProgress(20); // 20%

    var archer = await LoadDataFileAsync("archer.dat");
    splashScreen.UpdateProgress(40); // 40%

    var redMage = await LoadDataFileAsync("redMage.dat");
    splashScreen.UpdateProgress(60); // 60%

    var blueMage = await LoadDataFileAsync("blueMage.dat");
    splashScreen.UpdateProgress(80); // 80%

    var fistWarrior = await LoadDataFileAsync("fistWarrior.dat");
    splashScreen.UpdateProgress(100); // 100% -- all done

    // Determine the elapsed time to load all data files, and the remaining time to display the splash screen.
    var elapsedTime = DateTime.Now - startTime;
    var remainingTimeToWait = minimumDuration - elapsedTime;

    // If we've completed early, wait the remaining duration to show the splash screen.
    if(remainingTimeToWait > TimeSpan.Zero)
      await Task.Delay(remainingTimeToWait);

    // Done loading, close the splash screen.
    splashScreen.Close();
}
```

Now your `LoadDataFileAsync` method would look something like this:

```
Task<object> LoadDataFileAsync(string file)
{
    // Do your work to load your data file into an object here.
}
```

**EDIT**: I've been alerted to your comment that you are using .NET 4.0 so you have `Task` but not necessarily `async/await`. In this case, you can still break your code up into `Task` but will have to use `.ContinueWith()`.

See here for some good examples: [How to: Chain Multiple Tasks with Continuations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537612%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: A minor quibble, but `async/await` aren't available until C# 5.0. `Task` is available in C# 4.0.

Comment: @ledbutter A minor quibble, but `Task` has nothing to do with the version of C#, but rather the version of .NET used.

Comment: @user3134679 Anytime, the `async/await` stuff is amazing. I highly recommend learning it and mastering it by breaking up your code into `Task`-based blocks (when applicable).

Comment: @SiLo see the OP's latest comment to my question about what version of C# (ok, should have been .NET framework) he is using: he is on .NET 4.0, so `async/await` are not available to him.

Answer (score 1):

Open your form, in Timer_Tick:

```
void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.PerformStep();
    if(progressBar1.Value == 100)
    {
        Timer.Enabled = false;
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.Show();
        this.Hide(); //or Close maybe (test them both)
    }
}
```